# Tomcat does use driver configured on context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, context.xml

I give support to a legacy Java Web Application(Struts + Jsp) that runs in a Tomcat 9.0.10.
I configure the context.xml with the following data

```
<Resourse name="jdbc/APP_DEV" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="xxxx" password="xxxx" driverClassName="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SyDataSource" url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:server:port" />
```

This file (context.xml) is stored inside the war file in the META-INF folder.
The jar containing the "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SyDataSource" is inside Tomcat lib folder to.
Why Tomcat do not use this jar (jconn4-16.0) that contains the class com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SyDataSource and use instead the one in the tomcat-dbcp.jar more precisely the org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcpBasicSource.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Tomcat should be ignoring that entire line, since `<Resourse>` is misspelled. Correct spelling is `<Resource>`.

Comment: *FYI:* Tomcat only uses `META-INF/context.xml` the first time the webapp is deployed, copying the file to `TOMCAT_BASE/catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml` *(or whatever the webapp is named)*. Check that file to see what it says. You have to undeploy and redeploy, not just update, in order for a modified `context.xml` to be used.

Comment: @Andreas: whether to copy `META-INF/context.xml` or not depends on the [copyXML](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) setting, which defaults to false.